# Accessing resources through ids in a loop

Tags: android

I have long list of `EditText` elements in a layout actually these are for taking matrix inputs and matrix size can vary `3x3` `5x5` ...

The ids of the elements are in a series pattern like `11,12,13,21,22,23` ...
Now is there a way I can use these in a loop something like

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
a = findViewById("R.id.kernel1"+i);
```

Of course currently above with simple concatenation won't work, but is there a way?

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/convolutionMatrix"
android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixLayoutWidthHeight"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginOne"
android:background="@color/white1"
android:padding="@dimen/marginOne" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/marginOne"
    android:text="@string/matrixTitle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel11"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel12"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel13"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel14"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel15"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel21"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel22"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel23"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel24"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel25"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel31"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel32"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel33"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel34"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel35"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel41"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel42"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel43"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel44"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel45"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel51"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel52"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel53"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel54"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernel55"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Apply Kernel Mask" />
```

Comment: yes. see `Resources.getIdentifier()`

Comment: You could also put your ids in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like that. I have 6 variations of resources in one place I need to read.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
          String fname = "p" + i;
          int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "drawable", "com.example.yourproject");
          if (id == 0) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Lookup id for resource '"+fname+"' failed");
              // graceful error handling code here
          }
         scoresBm[i] =  (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);

  }
```

Comment: it is returning an int? how can i get the resource `EditText` from the id in case of `EditText`

Answer (score 2):

**Better Approach**

Example for accessing raw resources.

```
ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  id.add(getResources().getIdentifier("d"+i, "raw", getPackageName()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to do it pragmatically for example create new xml Layout

`layout.xml` content only

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

now in your activity add views to the layout for loop example

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   EditText etext = new EditText(this);
   //the Id and Tag must be set to call it back if we need info from this field
   etext.setId(i);
   etext.setTag("kernel"+i);
   //add edit text info here such as values and h/w etc
   etext.setText("my id : "+i+" , My Tags is : t"+i);

   //now add EditText field to parent
   parent.addView(etext);
}
```

and to call any EditText or any other view was added pragmatically , you can call it from tag or id for example

```
 //get last element added from loop by id
 EditText last = (EditText) parent.findViewById(10);
 //or get by tag 
 EditText last = (EditText) parent.findViewWithTag("kernel10");
```

hope this help