# Iterate over strings stored in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Here is a sample of my `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="intro_text_0">Hello </string>
<string name="intro_text_1">World </string>
<string name="intro_text_2">! </string>
.....
```

And I have an `EditText` field that I want to display those strings in succession when a user presses a button. What I am trying to do is get those strings in an array and iterate over them when a user clicks the button. First I need to actually find which strings I need to display...

`private String introTextToShow [] = new String[textLength];`

```
for (int i=0; i<textLength; i++)
        {
            // ADD the intro_string_i to the array!
            introTextToShow[i] = getString(R.string."intro_text_i"); // Oops
        }
```

My first though was using toString() to append the `i` on the rest of the text but this doesn't work. How can I iterate through the strings without directly entering their name in `R.string.intro_text_0`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904554/optimal-way-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-string-resources  https://stackoverflow.com/q/19799224/115145

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a `<string-array>` resource instead of a bunch of individual`<string>` resources?

Comment: Well I didn't know you can store string arrays as well in XML. That will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion is that you use a s[tring array resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) instead of a collection of individual string resources:

```
<string-array name="intro_text">
    <item>Hello </item>
    <item>World </item>
    <item>! </item>
</string-array>
```

and in the code:

```
private String introTextToShow [];

public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    introTextToShow = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.intro_text);
}
```

If you need to keep the intro text array as individual string resources for some other reason, you can retrieve them in a loop as follows:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String pkg = getPackageName();
for (int i=0; i<textLength; i++) {
    int resId = res.getIdentifier("intro_text_" + i, "string", pkg);
    introTextToShow[i] = res.getString(resId);
}
```